# 3-digit 16’s/15's complement representation of a negative number?

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

I have been trying to solve the following questions.

1. What is the following is the 3-digit 16’s complement representation
   of -128<sub>10</sub>.
2. What is the following is the 3-digit 15’s complement representation of -251<sub>10</sub>?

I got a result of 80H for the first question. But the answer sheet says the answer is F80H instead. I took the twos complement of 128 and convert it to hex accordingly.

What is the correct method/steps required to convert a negative decimal to an N complement's form?

Comment: If you're asked for 3 digits, then $\mathtt{80}_{\rm H}$ cannot possibly be right. It could be $\mathtt{080}_{\rm H}$, but where would the initial $\mathtt 0$ come from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to get a algorithm below but it doesn't work for the second question though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dig out a [StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60312/how-to-do-addition-subtraction-with-n-complement-eg-decimal-subtraction-via-10s) which had an algorithm for such problems.

$$-(Number) \equiv Complement^N- Number = Complement's \: representation.$$
Hence
$$-128 \equiv 16^3 - 128 = 3968 \: or \: F80H $$
Where N is the number of digits.