# how to subtract -13-4 using complements method?

Tags: arithmetic, schur-complement

i came up to these question on my homework:

*Complete needed actions for these decimal numbers using complementary arithmetic, to get the right result.*

```
(-13)-(4) = (-17)
```

Comment: I have not heard about this "complementary arithmetic". Could you tell us what that is?

Comment: I guess the tag " Schur complement " is not relevant. It applies to matrix. As for a similar problem see:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60312/how-to-do-addition-subtraction-with-n-complement-eg-decimal-subtraction-via-10s

Comment: What's complementary arithmetic?

Comment: probably something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse or the fact that it can be put in form $(-13)+(-4) = -17$